# Facebook: Create live stream without notification [facebook] or [facebook-graph-api] or [facebook-opengraph]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating live streaming events via API.
Everything's ok and the API are working great.

But ...
I remember there was a way to mute the notification that the friends are getting
whenever i create an event.

It disappeared from both the API and the GUI ?
Was it just a dream of mine ?
Not sure, but i cannot find it.

Does somebody have a workaround that allows me to create an event ( to test tokens and permissions for example ) without sending tons of notifications around ?

Thanks.
cp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way of doing so. But on using this method, live video will be removed from page timeline after it ends. I think this is acceptable as you are doing this only for testing purpose.

While creating live video using the end point with POST request at /{some ID}/live_videos , you need to send a parameter 'stream_type' with value "AMBIENT".

This means that the video is a 'Continuous Live Video' which means that it does not have any limit of maximum length of 4 hours and your viewers will not get notified when you start such live videos.

I hope this solves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks,  nice to know. but we definitely need the video to stay on the timeline afterwards; but i'll give it a try.